# Get the value of one column in gridview based on what row is clicked by the user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, linkbutton

I have this code and I can't get the value of student number based on what row is clicked by the user

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectEvent_click"  HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="StudentNumber">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentNumber" HeaderText="Student Number"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="F_name" HeaderText="First name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="L_name" HeaderText="Last name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Application">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApplication" runat="server" onClick = "SelectEvent_click"
                        Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**VB**

```
 Protected Sub SelectEvent_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label1.Text = GridView1.SelectedValue
        If GridView1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Response.Write(Label1.Text)
            Session("StudentNumber") = Label1.Text
            Response.Redirect("PCOApplicationView.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Write("Something bad happen please try again later!!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NamingContainer property on button click event, somthing like this :

```
Dim btn As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
GridViewRow = DirectCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

Comment: I use this code
 Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = TryCast(lnkbtn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
"
        Dim fileid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
but it gives me this error "Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @Abigail - Don't bind same method to Gridview's SelectedIndexChange and LinkButton's click. Change your method to handle button click instead of Gridview's selectedindex change.

Comment: Yes just removed it from the GridView (OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectEvent_click") and bind it from linkbutton only.   and now you will have selected row (in GridViewRow variable) of gridview where you have clicked you can get every value from it which you have bind.